# Java - WorNet - Synonym Detection (extjwnl 1.8)

Tags: java, wordnet, synonym

I hope you can help me...

How to get synonym of a word into an array using extended java word-net library

Waiting for your valuable response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking over the API, it seems that synonyms in WordNet are refered to as Synsets.

Assuming you have already called `System.setProperty("wordnet.database.dir", "<location_to_WordNet_database>/dict")`, you can declare and initalize a WordNetDatabase like so:

```
WordNetDatabase database = WordNetDatabase.getFileInstance();
```

and then declare and initialize a Synset array:

```
Synset[] synsets = database.getSynsets("your word", SynsetType.<WORDTYPE>/*like NOUN, or VERB*/);
```

I'm assuming that setting `SynsetType.NOUN` as the second parameter would create an array of synonyms which are nouns only.

You could then declare a Synset which corresponds to the synset array which you just initalized (for example, if you called `database.getSynsets("your word", SynsetType.NOUN)`, you would do this):

```
NounSynset nounSynset;
```

and finally you could iterate through your `synsets` array in a for loop, setting

```
nounSynset = (NounSynset) synsets[i];
```

and assign its primary word form to a `String` via

```
String currentSynonym = nounSynset.getWordForms()[0];
```

For more information, see [Java API for WordNet main page](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/) and the [documentation overview](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/doc/overview-summary.html)